# Testing an iOS Box OneCloud AppToApp application

Tags: ios, box-api

I'd like to integrate the Box OneCloud AppToApp framework into my application.  The integration seems easy enough, but I can't see any way to test the application with the OneCloud app.

At the moment, my app appears in the Box app's "Open in..." menu (because it registers the appropriate mime type associations), but the BoxAppToAppAPIInfo information indicates that this isn't a BoxAppToAppRequest.

Does anyone have any pointers on how we go about testing this?